# Trying to reduce array to smallest options in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am pulling availability data from a `SOAP` query. It is going into a sorted array that I am then displaying via a `lightslider`

Problem is that the items we are displaying are often in threes: Basic, Standard and Premium (but not always)

I need a way to reduce the array (or on output) to the smallest of the three possible options

Array input into the array sort looks like this: (snippet of larger array)

```
Array
(
       [WS_UTRUnitType] => Array
            (
                [0] => ALASA108.00 P
                [1] => ALASA11.50 B
                [2] => ALASA11.50 P
                [3] => ALASA11.50 S
                [4] => ALASA13.50 B
                [5] => ALASA13.50 P
                [6] => ALASA13.50 S
                [7] => ALASA15.75 P
                [8] => ALASA15.75 S
    )
      [WS_UTMonthlyRate] => Array
          (
            [0] => 650
            [1] => 139
            [2] => 149
            [3] => 145
            [4] => 159
            [5] => 169
            [6] => 165
            [7] => 175
            [8] => 170
       )
.
.
.
```

In this case, I would only want the `B's` where available and `S's` if `B's` not there

Hope I am making sense here :)

**Update: The remainder of the array would be also updated to remove the corresponding items**

Once the array is sorted, the info is then outputted via a loop

```
<ul id="image-gallery" class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden">
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {?>
                    <?php if ($sorted['WS_UTNoVacant'][$i] != "0") { // this only displays items that are available
...display the array data
}
```

Is it best to do the data selection at the start or during display.

Output I am looking for is an amended Array with only the required items in it. for the above example the output would then be

```
[WS_UTRUnitType] => Array
        (
            [0] => ALASA108.00 P
            [1] => ALASA11.50 B
            [4] => ALASA13.50 B
            [8] => ALASA15.75 S
)
```

With the other items stripped out

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Steven

Comment: post the desired result

Comment: desired result added above

Comment: See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#100813 - use array_filter in PHP

Comment: or it may be easier to flip the array around: create one record for each of the 8 types, so it looks like [0=>['WS_UTRUnitType'=>'ALASA108.00 P','WS_UTMonthlyRate'=>650, ...],1=>['WS_UTRUnitType'=>'ALASA11.50 B','WS_UTMonthlyRate'=>123,...], ...] and array_filter/usort that. Splitting the composite key (B, P, S) to a separate item will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) side effect of overwriting the values for same keys. To do this we have to sort the array in a right way firstly. `B` should go after `S`, and `S` after `P`:

```
$rank = [
    'B' => 1,
    'S' => 2,
    'P' => 3,
];

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($rank) {
    list($baseA, $suffixA) = explode(' ', $a);
    list($baseB, $suffixB) = explode(' ', $b);

    return $baseA === $baseB
        ? $rank[$suffixB] - $rank[$suffixA]
        : strcmp($baseA, $baseB);
});
```

Then we will create an associative array and take only values from it:

```
$result = array_values(
    array_combine(
        array_column(array_map(function ($element) {
            return explode(' ', $element);
        }, $array), 0), 
        $array
    )
);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b98f3a1746b90d9edd293ce38e30a8191c4c9c58).

Comment: Awesome, thanks, will try to implement now inside the rest of my code, cheers

Comment: can I contact you about implementation?

Comment: Have tried implementing the solution, but realize that the example I gave, was incomplete. The array I gave was itself inside another array, I have updated the question with the information